# How do I bypass the limitations of what MVC-CORE controllers can pass to the view?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, javascript-framework

From what I've read, I'm supposed to be using ViewModels to populate my views in MVC, rather than the model directly.   This should allow me to pass not just the contents of the model, but also other information such as login state, etc. to the view instead of using ViewBag or ViewData.   I've followed the tutorials and I've had both a model and a viewmodel successfully sent to the view.   The original problem I had was that I needed a paginated view, which is simple to do when passing a model alone, but becomes difficult when passing a viewmodel.

With a model of

```
public class Instructor {
    public string forename { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}
```

and a viewmodel of

```
public class InstructorVM {
    public Instructor Instructors { get; set; }
    public string LoggedIn { get; set; }
}
```

I can create a paginated list of the instructors using the pure model `Instructor` but I can't pass `InstructorVM` to the view and paginate it as there are other properties that aren't required in the pagination `LoggedIn` cause issues.   If I pass `InstructorVM.Instructors` to the view, I get the pagination, but don't get the `LoggedIn` and as this is just the model, I may has well have passed that through directly.

An alternative that was suggested was to convert/expand the viewmodel into a list or somesuch which would produce an object like this that gets passed to the view

```
instructor.forename = "dave", instructor.surname = "smith", LoggedIn="Hello brian"
instructor.forename = "alan", instructor.surname = "jones", LoggedIn="Hello brian"
instructor.forename = "paul", instructor.surname = "barns", LoggedIn="Hello brian"
```

where the `LoggedIn` value is repeated in every row and then retrieved in the row using `Model[0].LoggedIn`

Obviously, this problem is caused because you can only pass one object back from a method, either `Instructor`, `InstructorVM`, `List<InstructorVM>`, etc.

I'm trying to find out the best option to give me pagination (on part of the returned object) from a viewmodel while not replicating everything else in the viewmodel.

One suggestion was to use a JavaScript framework like React/Angular to break up the page into a more MVVM way of doing things, the problem with that being that despite looking for suggestions and reading 1001 "Best JS framework" lists via Google, they all assume I have already learned all of the frameworks and can thus pick the most suitable one from the options available.

When all I want to do is show a string and a paginated list from a viewmodel on a view.  At this point I don't care how, I don't care if I have to learn a JS framework or if I can do it just using MVC core, but can someone tell me how to do this thing I could do quite simply in ASP.NET?   If it's "use a JS framework" which one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the difficulty is here, as pagination and using a view model aren't factors that play on one another. Pagination is all about selecting a subset of items from a data store, which happens entirely in your initial query. For example, whereas you might originally have done something like:

```
var widgets = db.Widgets.ToList();
```

Instead you would do something like:

```
var widgets = db.Widgets.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage).ToList();
```

Using a view model is just a layer on top of this, where you then just map the queried data, no matter what it is onto instances of your view model:

```
var widgetViewModels = widgets.Select(w => new WidgetViewModel
{
    ...
});
```

If you're using a library like `PagedList` or similar, this behavior may not be immediately obvious, since the default implementation depends on having access to the queryset (in order to do the skip/take logic for you). However, `PagedList`, for example has `StaticPagedList` which allows you to create an `IPagedList` instance with an existing dataset:

```
var pagedWidgets = new StaticPagedList<WidgetViewModel>(widgetViewModels, pageNumber, itemsPerPage, totalItems);
```

There, the only part you'd be missing is `totalItems`, which is going to require an additional count query on the unfiltered queryset.

If you're using a different library, there should be some sort of similar functionality available. You'll just need to confer with the documentation.

Comment: I've been going through the Microsoft documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro and that's why I've ended up here.    Following their example, pagination is done in the back end controller, the relevant paginated subset of the model `Instructor`'s data or the viewmodel `InstructorVM.Instructor`'s data is passed from controller to view.   Passing the paginatable part of the viewmodel `InstructorVM.Instructor` from controller to view loses the other properties of the viewmodel, in this example `LoggedIn`

Comment: Pagination is about subsets of data, yes, I know that, my problem isn't pagination, it's getting all of the viewmodel, the paginated subset and all the other properties to the view, which the documentation doesn't do.   

And other examples are similarly, paginate-a-model / don't-paginate-a-viewmodel, hence me being here